# Coroutines unit testing: exceptions are being swallowed and test passes

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have the next test function:

```
@Test
fun `registerUser verify that loading was emitted`() {
    runBlocking {
        var emission = 0
        val viewModel = createSubject()
        viewModel.loading.observeForever {
            if (emission == 0) {
                assertNotNull(it)
                assertFalse(it!!) //MARK #1
                emission++
            }
        }
        async { viewModel.registerCommand.registerUser("asd") }.await()
        assertNotNull(viewModel.loading.value)
    }
}
```

I've wrapped `registerUser` invocation with `async` and `await` according to [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/61).

Inside `registerUser`:

```
fun registerUser(username: String) {
        launch {...
            withContext(ConfigurableDispatchers.IO) {...} 
            ...
        }
}
```

Whereas the class which has this function as a member inherits `CoroutineScope` and overrides `coroutineContext` with `ConfigurableDispatchers.Main + job`, whereas durint testing (in `@BeforeClass`-annotated method) `ConfigurableDispatchers.Main` is stubbed with

```
object : MainCoroutineDispatcher() {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override val immediate: MainCoroutineDispatcher
        get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException()

    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        block.run()
    }
}
```

Also, `ConfigurableDispatchers.IO` is stubbed with `Dispatchers.Unconfined`.

The problem is that assertion exception thrown from `MARK #1` is just being printed in the console and than just swallowed up. Test passes...
As I can see and as I've debugged - all this method body is being executed in a single thread, so if exception is being caught at the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, then, as I understand, **test should fail **. 
What is also interesting, when I wrap `MARK #1` (the failing line) with `try catch` block, whereas I am catching an `Exception` - nothing drops in the handler...

Why?

Comment: There are so many layers here that you probably don't need. One example: `registerUser` is not a `suspend fun`, wrapping it in `async-await` has no effect. The coroutine still runs on its own and `await` completes immediately. Not that you should be using `async-await` like that in the first place, it's an established anti-idiom.  Then, apparenty you `launch` and then immedietaly `withContext(ConfigurableDispatchers.IO)`. This is the same as `launch(ConfigurableDispatechers.IO)`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, thanks, will try that on monday

Comment: I think your `registerUser` should be a `suspend fun` that starts with `withContext(ConfigurableDispatchers.IO) { ... body ... }` and then you should pull the `launch` up into the callers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, "This is the same as launch(ConfigurableDispatechers.IO)" - actually here is an interesting moment: saying `launch` I mean that if this context will be cancelled, then cancel the whole outer coroutine, but with pure `IO` this is not the case, isn't it?

Comment: `IO` is just a dispatcher, not a coroutine scope. The choice of dispatcher doesn't affect cancellation behavior. Also, i don't think cancelling a job propagates to its parent. It is only the _failure_ of a job that propagates.

Comment: ah, yes, my mistake. thank you